# При запуске тг бота Ошибка Task exception was never retrieved

Tags: python, json, aiogram, requests

Всем привет! Пишу тг бота на aiogram для своего вуза, типо моя УИРС. Попытался запарсить сайт, но выдается ошибка при работе этого хендлера, что делать, в чем ошибка, помогите, пожалуйста. Ошибка появилась, когда изменил эту часть кода

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='lk')#########личный кабинет
async def lk_call(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id)

    r = requests.get('https://start.tpu.ru/guide.json')
    data = json.loads(r.content)  # saved guide.json

    await callback.message.answer(data[9]['content'],parse_mode='HTML',reply_markup=nazad)
```

до этого выглядел код так

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='lk')#########личный кабинет
async def lk_call(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id)
    await callback.message.answer('тут просто текст',parse_mode='HTML',reply_markup=nazad)
```

Вот результат работы, когда в боте пытаюсь нажать на эту кнопку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прочитай ошибку внизу - Can't parse entires: unsupported start tag "div" at byte offset 0 и копай отсюда

Comment: попробуй убрать parse_mode='HTML'

Comment: телеграм не может отобразить тег div